# Can't import DLL to Web API project (C#)

Tags: .net, windows, dll, import, dependencies

I'm trying to use a driver provided by a third party in order to control an emulator running locally on Windows (SAT.dll). I'm using VS2012. I thought about simply importing the dll by adding a reference to it in the project (References(right-click) -> Add Reference... ->Browse -> Add SAT.dll). When I tried this I got the following error message.

A reference to 'SAT.dll' could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

So, I looked into this issue. I found two possible solutions:

*. Use TlbImp.exe and the dll as its parameter. Here's the link to the SO question: [A reference to the dll could not be added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456758/a-reference-to-the-dll-could-not-be-added). Sadly I got the following error message:

http://s10.postimg.org/ru1fq98i1/Error2.png

The input file 'SAT.dll' is not a valid type library.

I'm not very experienced using DLLs or drivers, so I looked into this and found this SO question: [TLBIMP.EXE - Error TI0000 - *.dll is not a valid type library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005932/tlbimp-exe-error-ti0000-dll-is-not-a-valid-type-library). I'm not sure how VS 2012 may affect the usage of the driver.

2. Use dependency walker to figure out if the dll doesn't miss any dependencies. I ran depends.exe with SAT.dll and got the following:

http://s22.postimg.org/bbyemp76p/Dependency.png

I don't know if something's wrong with the DLL or not.

P.S. Some devs from Brazil use this driver using Delphi. I addressed them but sadly I haven't gotten any answers yet. Is there someway that it is somehow Delphi specific? Is that possible?

Thanks for your time and patience,

Sincerely .NET noob

Comment: what kind of dll is this, pascal, c, java, or c++? doesn't sound like it's com or .net

Comment: Well, I don't know..... The documentation for the emulator is pretty poor.. They don't specify nothing concerning the origins of the dll. By the way, the emulator comes with a Java application that interacts with it. Does this mean the dll is only usable in Java? I guess I should have mentioned that earlier.....

Comment: with Java we cant create DLL. Looks like this is C++ dll. If you want to use the functionality of C++ in C# then you can use PInvoke (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx ) provided if you know what is the method which is exported and its signature.

Comment: Well, the emulator is a Java application. Is it possible that the driver is a C++ dll?

Comment: It is a C dll. I feel a bit silly not noticing that in the Dependency Tracker. Thanks for the insight!